# Programmatically modify existing mongo document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript

**Resolved, the issue was with the PUT request , I had to specify the header properly and go on with one at a time.**

```
curl -X PUT -H "Accept: application/json" -d "prenom=Maxwell" localhost:3000/contact/51df5cec5e88a2bbce7fac05
```

I'm trying to modify a mongodb document via coffeescript in a node.js application I'm currently working on and when I try :

```
 curl -X PUT -d '{"nom": "House", "prenom": "Maxwell"}' localhost:3000/contact/51ddb907ae3267d6154a3e64
```

on this

```
{
  "_id": "51ddb907ae3267d6154a3e64",
  "archive": 1,
  "nom": "Bir",
  "prenom": "Sim"
}
```

The ID and the routes are correct, so I'm pretty sure the error lies in the javascript logic but I can't seem to grasp the right angle to work it. Here is the defective code :

```
   exports.modifyContact = (req, res) ->
     db.collection "data-center", (erreur, collection) ->
       collection.update { _id: new mongo.BSONPure.ObjectID(req.params.id) }, { $set: req.body } , (erreur, resultat) ->
         res.send resultat
         res.end()
```

and the result is

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("51df4ad424f6d9207cc3e2d5"),
  "nom" : "Bir",
  "nom": "House",
  "prenom": "Maxwell" : "",
  "prenom" : "Sim" 
}
```

I can't seem to find an effective way to set missing value and modify value already in there. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try instead:

```
exports.modify = (req, res) ->
  fields = if (typeof req.body == 'string') then JSON.parse(req.body) else req.body
  db.collection "data-center", (erreur, collection) ->
    // check erreur here
    collection.update { _id: new mongo.BSONPure.ObjectID(req.params.id) }, { $set: fields }, (erreur, resultat) ->
      // check erreur here
      res.send resultat
      res.end()
```

It is important to note that inserting data directly from req.body without some sort of validation/content checking is **not** secure and should be avoided (even if it works as expected).

Comment: I agree with you , I simplified my code so it would show the essential part I have issues with. I tried your suggestion and it seems like it would work but i get this Converting circular structure to JSON error,..

Comment: I'm sorry, I've updated the answer. `collection.find` should be `collection.update`.

Comment: it does not replace the fields , it just add an object to the object, do you know how could I just get the field value to replace the object field value ?

Comment: What are the contents of req.body? Also, have you used the exact code as above or have you modified it in some way when testing the solution?

Comment: content of req.body is "{'nom' : 'aName', 'prenom': 'aFirstName'}" that I curl -X PUT -d "{'nom' : 'aName', 'prenom': 'aFirstName'}" localhost:3000/url in the exact same way as the code above

Comment: Could you please report the code you're using (after trying my solution) with the contents of the result document after the update?

Comment: It gets me the exact same result, thought.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is then. This solution does work and I've tested it locally. Either I'm missing something or there's some local issue with your setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just "merge" a set of fields into an existing object you do it this way

```
test:PRIMARY> db.t2.insert({b:1})
test:PRIMARY> db.t2.update({b:1}, {$set: {a:1, c:2}})
test:PRIMARY> db.t2.find({b:1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520a3f10e2d66ef50d3b042b"), "a" : 1, "b" : 1, "c" : 2 }
```

Ah yeah and for the json issue, you cannot use the "original" object to return as json. You need to perform a findOne to retrieve the updated object from mongodb or change to using a findAndModify with the parameter new to get the changed object in a single operation. The existing object might well have have circular references.